# how to sum up the document in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

Now I want to query "SUM the number of Score between Q1 to Q5 (the result should be 4). Attached the collection snapshot of mlab.

[mlab snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBAo7.png)

```
      db.temp.aggregate({ $match: {
        $and: [
            { QuestionNo: { $gte: 1 } },
            { QuestionNo: { $lte: 5 } }
        ]
      }},
      { $group: { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$Score" } } });
```

I dont see any response in console. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to over complicate your match query. What you want is basically all QuestionNo's between 1-5. I assume your documents look something like this:

```
{
    "QuestionNo" : 1,
    "Score" : 55
}

/* 2 */
{
    "QuestionNo" : 2,
    "Score" : 33
}
etc...
```

If you want to sum all the results then you can do

```
db.temp.aggregate(
{ 
    $match: {
        QuestionNo: { $gte: 1 , $lte: 5 } 
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        sum: { $sum: "$Score"}
    }
}
)
```

If you want to group them by `QuestionNo` then you can do this:

```
db.temp.aggregate(
{ 
    $match: {
        QuestionNo: { $gte: 1 , $lte: 5 } 
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$QuestionNo",
        sum: { $sum: "$Score"}
    }
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Your answer really helps!!